# Mvc using 2 @model In View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi guys I have a view that populate the data into table
I have this in my view

```
@model IEnumerable<"Model">
```

and i have something like this in my view

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Audit_ID)
            </td>
            //rest of the code
         </tr>
    }
```

my problem is how to input something this in view

```
@model DAL.EODAuditModel
@model IEnumerable<"Model">
```

because i want to do this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
            <legend>Employee</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
               @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
           </div>
</fieldset>
}
```

The problem is I cannot do this because I have define 2 @model in view which will throw an exception

I want to this Because this view will view the records and create new records.
Thanks.

Update 2: I edit my code base on suggestions

Model Code:

```
public class EODAuditModel
    {
        public EODAuditModel()
        {
            this.ExistingRecords = new List<EODAuditModel>();
        }
        public int Audit_ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public List<EODAuditModel> ExistingRecords { get; set; }
    }
```

View code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ExistingRecords)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
```

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            EODAuditBL eodBl = new EODAuditBL();
            List<EODAuditModel> eodModel = eodBl.GetEODAudit.ToList();
            return View(eodModel);
        }
```

GetEODAuditCode:

```
public IEnumerable<EODAuditModel> GetEODAudit
{
}
```

when I run the program the compilation is ok but I get this error in 
the web page

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DAL.EODAuditModel]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type 'DAL.EODAuditModel'.

Comment: See the updated answer, I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah thanks my friend you really save my day thanks for the time :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a new model class that contains both `IEnumerable<"Model">` and `Name` property.

```
public class AuditViewModel
{
    public AuditViewModel()
    {
        this.ExistingRecords = new List<EODAuditModel>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<EODAuditModel> ExistingRecords { get; set; }
}
```

Define the model in your view as below

```
@model AuditViewModel
```

and change the `foreach` block to this

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ExistingRecords)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Audit_ID)
        </td>
        //rest of the code
     </tr>
}
```

**UPDATE**

Looks like you got the error because in the controller you passed an instance of `List<DAL.EODAuditModel>` instead of `DAL.EODAuditModel` to the view. Change your controller to this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    EODAuditBL eodBl = new EODAuditBL();
    List<EODAuditModel> auditList = eodBl.GetEODAudit.ToList();

    EODAuditModel model = new EODAuditModel();
    model.ExistingRecords = auditList;

    return View(model);
}
```

I changed `eodModel` to `auditList` to avoid confusion between the model and the existing records.

Comment: Where did you get the error? Can you show which line of code?

Comment: public AuditViewModel()
    {
        this.ExistingRecords = new List<EODAuditModel>();
    }

Comment: Are you sure that method is placed in `AuditViewModel` class? If you use a different class name for the model, then the constructor must also have the same name.

Comment: I update my code for your reference thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Use child actions. This is what they're there for. They can only be used for GET requests, so for something like this, the model definition for your view will be the create instance, while the model for your child action will be the list of existing items:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var eodBl = new EODAuditBL();
    return View(eodBl);
}

[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ListEODAuditBLs()
{
    // look up from database
    var eodModel = db.EODAudits.ToList();
    return PartialView(eodModel);
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model Namespace.To.EODAuditBL

@Html.Action("ListEODAuditBLs")

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
       </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**ListEODAuditBLs.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Namespace.To.EODAuditBL>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy)
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```